# Python for Keithley

Tags: python, python-2.7, ethernet, digital, analog-digital-converter

I hooked up the Keithley 2701 DMM, installed the software and set the IPs right. I can access and control the instrument via the internet explorer webpage and the Keithley communicator. When I try to use python, it detects the instrument
i.e. `a=visa.instrument("COM1")` doesn't give an error.

I can write to the instrument as well:

```
a.write("*RST")
a.write("DISP:ENAB ON/OFF")
a.write("DISP:TEXT:STAT ON/OFF")
```

etc all don't give any error but no change is seen on the instrument screen.
However when I try to read back, `a.ask("*IDN?")` etc give me an error
saying timeout expired before operation completed.

I tried redefining as:

```
a=visa.instrument("COM1",timeout=None)
a=visa.instrument("TCPIP::<the IP adress>::1354::SOCKET")
```

and a few other possible combinations but I'm getting the same error.

Please do help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with communicating to the 2701 might be an invalid termination character. By default the termination character has the value `CR+LF` which is `“\r\n”`.

The python code to set the termination character is:

```
theInstrument = visa.instrument(“TCPIP::<IPaddress>::1394::SOCKET”, term_chars = “\n”)
```

or

```
theInstrument = visa.instrument(“TCPIP::<IPaddress>::1394::SOCKET”)
theInstrument.term_chars = “\n”
```

I hope this helps,